# What is difference between trivial FD and two cyclic FD's

Tags: relational-algebra, functional-dependencies, bcnf

In the Complete Book by Ullman and Widom I've read that with two attributes (A and B) we have four cases for FD's. Second and third are A -> B and B -> A, so they are easier. But I don't understand what the difference between trivial dependency «B is a subset of A» and cyclic FD's A -> B and B -> A. Aren't they the same?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer science, and belongs on cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Oh, maybe I'm in a hurry little bit. Am I right that the trivial FD between A and B means "with one A we will have only one B which is an element from A set"? So that way I'd got the point.

Comment: Maybe. I had some doubts about where to post it but I found a lot of questions about BCNF here.

Answer (score 0):

With two attributes you have four cases:

- A -> B (this means you also have the trivial FDs: A -> A, B -> B)
- B -> A (with trivial FDs as above)
- A -> B, B -> A (with trivial FDs as above)
- no non-trivial FDs. This means you only have the trivial FDs A -> A, B -> B. This means that the two attributes are independent.

A "real-world" example of case 3 could be two attributes: SSN (social security number of a person) and passport_number of a person. Each one is the consequence of the other.

An example of case 4 could be two attributes: SSN (social security number of a person) and book_title. The two attributes are completely independent. One does not imply the other.